# PAYMENT_CREATION_ERROR

Tags: paypal

The sandbox test has been succeed.
I have two account. Both are JP business account and have valid card and the sender account have balance. The live test always failed.
Here is the log.
PayPal SDK: Request has failed with error: PAYMENT_CREATION_ERROR - There was a problem setting up this payment. Please visit the PayPal website to check your account. (422) | PayPal Debug-ID: 12d9f9213ed4b [live, PayPal iOS SDK 2.11.5]

Comment: Anyone could tell me about "PayPal Debug-ID: 12d9f9213ed4b"?

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question without further information about what you are doing. (By the way, note that the actual error code in this message seems to be `422`, so you might want to search for that.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sand box test account and it is similar with live account, this error could happen. Make sure your sandbox test account and the account you are using to test are different then try again